# Sync up data in ADF table after update in DB table done outside ADF environment

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a jsff page inside a bounded task flow. It displays a table. Each row of table has an edit icon. on click of which a new jsff page opens containing the information of the selected row ready to be edited.
Here user can update and  save the information and check the information back on the first page by clicking a Done button on second page.Pretty much simple.

The problem is I have some complex implementation due to which I should not update the row information through ADF way. I take the information entered by the user and pass it to plane java file. There in the plane java file I instantiate an AM and update the information through this AM.
The problem with this approach is that when I click the Done button to come back on table page to check the saved data, the data on the table is stale.

This seems as If the table is being updated outside the ADF framework and so it is not aware of the underlying the data change hence the ADF UI table is not synced with physical table automatically.

JDev : 11.1.1.7.11

Options tried : Upon click of Done button I tried to requery the VO of ADF table by
                         1) Clearing the VO cache row and repopulating it
                         2) Re executing the iterator binding
                         3) Re executing the iterator binding programatically.

Thanks

Comment: PS this question is already https://community.oracle.com/thread/3822527  here but I haven't got the answer.

Comment: 1) Creating (manual) an AM instance is something you should avoid. Use your binding layer to communicate with your Model. 2) At what point do you go 'outside of your ADF'?

Comment: 1) I know it is not a recommended practice but my implementation is such that i have to do it this way.
2) I am in an inline frame within the jsff page and in that inline frame a servlet is called which responds with a PDF output. at this point i am outside ADF env 'cuz servlet is tranditional web app.